# Calculate RMSE in two matrix when they include Nan value in Python Code

Tags: python-3.x, nan, numpy-ndarray

I am a beginner at using Python code, and I have a problem with calculating the RMSE in two matrixes when they include Nan values.

For example, I have two matrixes, which include a couple of columns with Nan values. How can I calculate the RMSE value in each column?

X = ndarray with shape (1500, 27), y = ndarray with shape (1500, 27)

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to calculate it but I get Nan value each time. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have to say that I know how to remove the Nan column in each matrix but I don't want to do it. I want to calculate each RMSe value for each 27 columns .

Comment: Please note that the code have changed. You need to account for `not nan` cells only. So, I've added `skipped_cells`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ndarray is very small. So, just iterate over rows and columns and use

```
    import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 10, 50, -np.nan, 0, np.nan],[1, 2, 10, 30, -np.nan, 0, np.nan]])
arr2 = np.array([[5, 2, 10, 50, 10, 0, np.nan],[1, 2, 10, 50, -np.nan, 0, np.nan]])


for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
    rmse = 0
    skipped_cells = 0
    for j in range(arr1.shape[1]):
        if np.isnan(arr1[i, j]) or np.isnan(arr2[i, j]):
            skipped_cells += 1
            continue
        rmse += (arr1[i,j] - arr2[i,j])**2
    print((rmse/(arr1.shape[1]-skipped_cells))**(1/2))
```

Now, if you are working with larger arrays AND your bottleneck is this part - look for set operations. Briefly. Use `np.isnan`, then apply `np.where` to substitute `nan` with zeros in both arrays. Then compute rmse. Finally, correct for the fact that some values were nan. That is multiply by sqrt of the length of a row and and divide by `(np.sum(is_not_nan))**0.5`